# Why Eventhub async receiver is fetching just 30-35 messages per minute?

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I have a `async_receive` method of Eventhub developed in `python` and also has a `checkpoint` with it. The code was taken from the official Eventhub sample [github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/async_samples/recv_with_checkpoint_store_async.py).

**Problem-** Using the above-mentioned code, I am just able to `receive 20-35 messages per minute` if I keep the receiver on for the whole day whereas my Eventhub has a lot of **stream data ingested (~200 messages per Minute)**. The enqueued time at eventhub for a message is now lagging behind by **90 minutes** due to poor throughput at the receiver's end which means that `the data that got enqueued at X minute in the Eventhub got pulled out of it at X+90 minutes`

**Investigation-** I tried to look at the [**receive subclass** in the Eventhub python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/azure/eventhub/aio/_consumer_client_async.py) and came across a `prefetch parameter` (line 318) which is set to `300 by default`. If this is already set to 300 then I should be able to pull more than 30-35 messages by default.

Any idea on how can I increase my pull capacity? I'm stuck at this point and have no direction forward, any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT 1-
I'm now attaching my Python Code as shown below-

```
import asyncio
import json
import logging
import os
import sys
import time
from datetime import date

import requests
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio import BlobCheckpointStore
import log_handler
import threading
import traceback

try:
    ## Set env variables
    CONNECTION_STR = os.environ["ECS"].strip()
    EVENTHUB_NAME = os.environ['EN'].strip()
    EVENTHUB_CONSUMER = os.environ["EC"].strip()
    API = os.environ['API_variable'].strip()
    AZURE_BLOB_CONNECTION_STR = os.environ["ACS"].strip()
    BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME = os.environ["BCN"].strip()
    BLOB_ACCOUNT_URL = os.environ["BAU"].strip()

    PREFETCH_COUNT = int(os.environ["PREFETCH_COUNT"])
    MAX_WAIT_TIME = float(os.environ["MAX_WAIT_TIME"])


except Exception as exception:
    logging.debug(traceback.format_exc())
    logging.warning(
        "*** Please check the environment variables for {}".format(str(exception)))
    sys.exit()

def API_CALL(event_data):
    """
    Sends the request to the API
    """
    
    try:
        url = event_data['image_url']
        payload = {"url": url}

        ## API call to the server
        service_response = requests.post(API, json=payload)
        logging.info(f"*** service_response.status_code : {service_response.status_code}")
        cloud_response = json.loads(
            service_response.text) if service_response.status_code == 200 else None
        today = date.today()
        response_date = today.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
        response_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
        response_data = {
            "type": "response_data",
            "consumer_group": EVENTHUB_CONSUMER,
            'current_date': response_date,
            'current_time': response_time,
            'image_url': url,
            'status_code': service_response.status_code,
            'response': cloud_response,
            'api_response_time': int(service_response.elapsed.total_seconds()*1000),
            "eventhub_data": event_data
        }
        logging.info(f"*** response_data {json.dumps(response_data)}")
        logging.debug(f"*** response_data {json.dumps(response_data)}")
    except Exception as exception:
        logging.debug(traceback.format_exc())
        logging.error(
            "**** RaiseError: Failed request url %s, Root Cause of error: %s", url, exception)


async def event_operations(partition_context, event):

    start_time = time.time()
    data_ = event.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8')
    json_data = json.loads(data_)
    
    ## forming data payload
    additional_data = {
        "type": "event_data",
        "consumer_group": EVENTHUB_CONSUMER,
        "image_name": json_data["image_url"].split("/")[-1]
    }

    json_data.update(additional_data)

    logging.info(f"*** Data fetched from EH : {json_data}")
    logging.debug(f"*** Data fetched from EH : {json_data}")

    API_CALL(json_data)

    logging.info(f"*** time taken to process an event(ms): {(time.time()-start_time)*1000}")


def between_callback(partition_context, event):
    """
    Loop to create threads
    """
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(event_operations(partition_context, event))
    loop.close()


async def on_event(partition_context, event):
    """
    Put your code here.
    Do some sync or async operations.
    If the operation is i/o intensive, async will have better performanceself.
    """

    t1 = time.time()
    _thread = threading.Thread(target=between_callback, args=(partition_context, event))
    _thread.start()
    logging.info(f"*** time taken to start a thread(ms): {(time.time()-t1)*1000}")
    logging.info("*** Fetching the next event")
    
    ## Update checkpoint per event
    t2 = time.time()
    await partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)
    logging.info(f"*** time taken to update checkpoint(ms): {(time.time()-t2)*1000}")

async def main(client):
    """
    Run the on_event method for each event received
    Args:
        client ([type]): Azure Eventhub listener client
    """
    
    try:
        async with client:
            # Call the receive method. Only read current data (@latest)
            logging.info("*** Listening to event")
            await client.receive(on_event=on_event,
                                 prefetch=PREFETCH_COUNT,
                                 max_wait_time=MAX_WAIT_TIME)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("*** Stopped receiving due to keyboard interrupt")
    except Exception as err:
        logging.debug(traceback.format_exc())
        print("*** some error occured :", err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    ## Checkpoint initialization
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore(
        blob_account_url=BLOB_ACCOUNT_URL,
        container_name=BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME,
        credential=AZURE_BLOB_CONNECTION_STR
    )
    
    ## Client initialization
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        CONNECTION_STR,
        consumer_group=EVENTHUB_CONSUMER,
        eventhub_name=EVENTHUB_NAME,
        checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store, #COMMENT TO RUN WITHOUT CHECKPOINT
        logging_enable=True,
        on_partition_initialize=on_partition_initialize,
        on_partition_close=on_partition_close,
        idle_timeout=10,
        on_error=on_error,
        retry_total=3
    )
    
    logging.info("Connecting to eventhub {} consumer {}".format(
        EVENTHUB_NAME, EVENTHUB_CONSUMER))
    logging.info("Registering receive callback.")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main(client))
    except KeyboardInterrupt as exception:
        pass
    finally:
        loop.stop()
```

> **Execution-flow** main()-->on_event()-->Thread(between_callback-->API_CALL)-->update_checkpoint

Comment: How is the Event Hub provisioned? And just to make sure, you didn't alter any of the code of the example? Because if you do some time consuming processing... well....

Comment: Eventhub has 2 partitions and other than fetching a few details from the payload like filename and timestamp there is no heavy post processing.

Comment: What do you do in on_event? You should remove any code that can slow down message processing and find out whether message delivery is slow or the processing itself. Most of the time, it is the developer's code spending cycles waiting on downstream writes. See if this is the case for you as well.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca I think I understand it, in my on_event function I call an API which consumes the event and this API takes approximately 2-3 seconds to complete, here's the code https://ideone.com/CNjTcH. How can I send my event to this API without hindering the Event Process?

Comment: on_event delivers one event at a time. You should batch process the events and reduce the number of I/O calls. Call 'api_call' in your code on an interval, say every 10 seconds. Please note that I am assuming that your downstream can handle batch writes.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca Got it, Or i will just create a function that can be executed in a thread or some background process. Thanks

Comment: @SerkantKaraca I tried threading the events, but the result is still the same. I am still getting `~30 messages` per minute which are accounting for `30 threads` consuming `500 MB as the net Memory`. Free memory is around 2.5 GB. Prefetch parameter is set to `1000`. I'm on a dead end again as previously I thought that my API call might be causing this but now, I'm not sure.

Comment: For testing purposes only comment out everything in the processing code and just log the number of messages received. See how fast you can receive. Prefetch size of 1000 is good enough. This exercise will point whether the issue is in EH SDK or the processing code.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca I tried it a few days ago, pulling images from `-1 position` does not give a problem, actually `I was able to pull 0.1 Million Data points in less than 5 hours`, so I can say that SDK for -1 is fine. I was digging deeper in my codebase and decided to add time logs to check the time consumption at each stage, I am disturbed to see that `Checkpoint update per event` is varying from `0.05 seconds to 60+ seconds`. Please see the snapshot here - `https://imgur.com/a/wPOGg3e` I'm assuming theoretically that until checkpoint is updated new event can not be fetched right?

Comment: @SerkantKaraca Also added the complete code above

Comment: Correct, the event handler won't receive the next event before checkpoint call is complete. Regarding the checkpoint latency, I don't think checkpoint update can take a minute unless your app is experiencing network-related issues. Start from storage account metrics and make sure the storage account is healthy and not throttling requests. Then switch to the client-side and check ephemeral port usage and especially number of connections that the client is creating to the storage endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function for the receiver in the below format when we can able to get the events and run them until they complete.

```
import asyncio
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio import BlobCheckpointStore
async def on_event(partition_context, event):
 # Print the event data.
 print("Received the event: \"{}\" from the partition with ID: \"{}\"".format(event.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8'), partition_context.partition_id))
 # Update the checkpoint so that the program doesn't read the events
 # that it has already read when you run it next time.
 await partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)
async def main():
 # Create an Azure blob checkpoint store to store the checkpoints.
 checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string("AZURE STORAGE CONNECTION STRING", "BLOB CONTAINER NAME")
 # Create a consumer client for the event hub.
 client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string("EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING", consumer_group="$Default", eventhub_name="EVENT HUB NAME", checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store)
 async with client:
 # Call the receive method. Read from the beginning of the partition (starting_position: "-1")
 await client.receive(on_event=on_event, starting_position="-1")
if __name__ == '__main__':
 loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
 # Run the main method.
 loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Also as per the suggest in the comment, call the API on an interval bases.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the code is already in this format, it's just that I'm doing extra steps in on_event function that I will move to background using a thread or something.